# How to fix blurry font in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015 community edition and have noticed that the default font in the text editor is blurry compared to the VS 2013 community edition which uses the same font.  I have these both on my machine and can see that VS 2013 renders the font more smoothly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?   I'm on a Surface pro 4 with Windows 10

Visual Studio 2015 with blurry font
[image: VS 2015]

Visual Studio 2013 with nice crisp font
[image: VS 2013]

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question: While it is easy to fix it will most probably pop up again in the future. I don't see any reason to close it.

Comment: You still have a problem: look at uppercase letters L and M, lowercase m, ... The antialiasing is badly hurting. More advanced fonts and/or renderer wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set the zoom level in 2015 to 100%:

[image]

Comment: Best arrow ever ;-)

Comment: Sometimes a fix is a mousescroll away

Comment: @UweKeim I made it with Paint.NET, so I'd rather call it a pointer ;)

Comment: This has been the pain in the next for the past 3 weeks. I thought I got something in my eyes all the time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 24):

For those who have blurry fonts problem because of two displays (e.g. one is 100%-scaled, and other is 125%), just make other display (on which fonts are blurry) main.
[image: set main display]

> In order for the changes to take effect you must **sign out** or **restart**.

Comment: I had to restart my laptop before the text went clear but this was definitely the answer to my issue.

Comment: This generally won't work. E.g., if you have one FHD and one 4K monitor, the non-main monitor will always be blurry when using different scalings. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25097/font-is-blurry-due-to-not-supporting-mixed-mode-dp.html)

Comment: I guess if clear text is scaled down, it remains clear. And if clear text is scaled up, it becames blurry. But even if it's not the case, anyway that worked for me.

Comment: Now, when I look closely, I indeed see that on non-main display it is a little blurry, but that is neglectable.

Comment: jonaglon, your advise to reboot pc really helped me. You should post it as standalone answer.

Answer (score 8):

In your 2015 example, you have the zoom set to 98% (see the drop-down in the bottom left corner).

Doing this in my version also made the text 'blurry' and setting it back to 100% made it crisp.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Unchecking this fixed my problem in VS 2019. No need to set zoom to 100%.

Comment: This also works in Visual Studio 2017. I found the two checkboxes underneath also had to be unchecked for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be way too old topic to reply, but I faced exactly the same issue in MSVS 2022. Fonts look OK in context menus, list of files etc., but look ugly in the code editor. It seemed "fat" and not sharp. The solution which worked for me is to set **Text formatting** to **Display** in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced.

Before and after to compare:

[image: Before and after the settings change]

Solution was found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-a-different-font-than-consolas-is-ugly/1587095

Answer (score -3):

**How to fix blurry font in Visual Studio 2015**

**Tool**: Regedit  
**Issue**: Blurry fonts in editor pages and solution explorer.  
**Variant**: Blurry Editor Only - read prior issues 
**Problem** : BOTH PANES, Windows and/or Text Editor / Solution Explorer blurry 
**What did not work:**
Changing the editor e.g. The round-trip from 100% to 98% and back.  It worked then failed

My regedit change was from 64 back to 100 - fixed in seconds

UPDATE: It returned but less troublesome - Only quirk was the Find/Replace buttons stuck as in Match Case/Whole Word.

Tonto says news at the end of another blurry night

The regedit changes remained in place. Perhaps the resetting occurs during launch - testing, testing and test again

UPDATE: Scroll the mouse one row entire page fixed - Solution Explorer operational (one down)

Comment: If you have an answer, put it in the answer field, a link is not necessary.